# Can I define my own "set of predefined computers" in Windows Firewall?

Tags: windows-firewall

According to [Microsoft](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee806447.aspx), I can.

> Note:
>   You can also define or select a set of computer from a drop-down menu that has a predefined set of computer. Refer to the Windows Firewall with Advanced Security documentation to find  out how to define a set of computers from which to select. There are some existing collections  of computers available already.

But I can't find it anywhere in the firewall documentation.

Does anybody know how to define a custom "set of predefined computers" in Windows Firewall with Advanced Security?

I'm using Windows Server 2008 R2 and Windows Firewall with Advanced Security version 6.1

Answer (score 3):

What the 'predefined set of computers' is referring to is if you do the following

1. Open “**Windows Firewall with Advanced Security**”
2. Right click "**Inbound Rules**" select new rule
3. Select **Custom** > **Next**
4. Select "**All  programs**" > **Next**
5. Select "**protocol type**" > **Any** > **Next**
6. Under "**Which local IP ......**" select **Any IP address**
7. Under "**Which remote IP ....**" select **These IP addresses** > **Add** >
   Predefined set of computers >

[image]

So the predefined set of computers is actually just Default Gateway, WINS Servers, DNS Servers, DHCP Servers or Local Subnet.

They make it sound like you are able to create a local group that contains a list of computers to specify, but that does not seem to be the case :(   I think the only options are to set a range of computers via IP Address or IP Subnet instead of by computer name.

Anyway, continuing on -

8.Select "**Allow the connection**" > **Next**

9.Leave all three ticked > **Next**

10.Give the rule a name > **Finish**

Hope that helps (somewhat) :)

Comment: David, did this answer your question?   If so please mark my response as the correct answer.  If not, please elaborate further so someone can further assist you.

Answer (score -3):

Although I've only just started reading it, [this article](http://www.windowsecurity.com/articles/Windows-Server-2008-Firewall-Advanced-Security-Part1.html) looks pretty in depth and therefore might help.